# .gitignore can't ignore folder directories or files

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

My problem here that i get a list ignore files,dirs but they still be available for committing.

For example: I just remove cache by command:

> git rm --cached *DATN_2015.BLL.dll
>
> git commit -m "Delete some files from repository"

so i get all these files and commit to remove > push. Then, i update my file:

> .gitignore

with:

> *DATN_2015.BLL.dll

but i don't know why when i rebuild project's solutions, they appear a new change for this file DATN_2015.BLL.dll and it still be available for committing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What `.gitignore` is doing, is ignoring new untracked files to the repository.

Make sure your `.gitignore` is at the root of your repository (next to the `.git`).

If you want to ignore changes made to already tracked files, use this command :

```
git update-index --assume-unchanged <file>
```

[More informations here.](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/18/temporarily-ignoring-files.html)

Comment: so, i can't ignore these files: http://www.upsieutoc.com/images/2015/07/20/Captureb2cfe.png

I use your command, it's worked on first time, but when i rebuild solution, they appear again

Comment: First you need to remove them using git rm --cached, and commit that change. Then, your .gitignore changes will be applied.

Comment: thank you blue but it still not work, do you have skype ? .gitignore just ignore my new folder directories, i have tried:


1. Add ignore file list to .gitignore

2. Remove cache file list by rm --cached myfiles

3. Commit and Push

4. Try to use your command and it's ok on my first use, but still appear after i rebuild solution, still available for committing.

Comment: Sounds like there's something you're doing wrong. Please ask a new question on stack overflow with all the relevant code copied from your terminal, like your .gitignore file and your git status.